# Initializing a matrix to infinity in python

Tags: python, infinity

How to initialize a matrix to a very large number, say to infinity.

Similar to initializing all elements to zero:
sample = np.matrix((np.zeros(50,50))

I want to initalize to infinity

How to do it in python?

Comment: You must understand that a computer exists in a finite world. Perhaps what you're asking is how to dynamically allocate an array.

Comment: "infinity" is _not_ "a very large number".

Comment: @Lescurel infinity *is* a value representable in float numbers. Check out [the format specification for IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) for details on how that works

Comment: @GPhilo Thanks, I've learned something today

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is `np.inf`in `numpy`

```
>>> sample = np.matrix(np.ones((50,50)) * np.inf)
>>> sample
matrix([[ inf,  inf,  inf, ...,  inf,  inf,  inf],
    [ inf,  inf,  inf, ...,  inf,  inf,  inf],
    [ inf,  inf,  inf, ...,  inf,  inf,  inf],
    ..., 
    [ inf,  inf,  inf, ...,  inf,  inf,  inf],
    [ inf,  inf,  inf, ...,  inf,  inf,  inf],
    [ inf,  inf,  inf, ...,  inf,  inf,  inf]])
```

Comment: Use of this, import numpy as np                                                                sample = np.matrix(np.ones(4,4) * np.inf) shows an error                                    a = empty(shape, dtype, order)
TypeError: data type not understood

Comment: @Dr.SantleCamilus You missed a couple of brackets inside `np.ones()`

Comment: yes, you are right, it works now

Comment: is there a way I can mix random integers with 2d matrix having infinity values?

Answer (score 3):

Numpy has infinity object, you can call it by `np.inf`.